# How to write DB dump into seeds file in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, dump, data-migration

I have two rails applications with similar Postgres databases.

I am trying to find out how to get data from 1st rails app,
and put it into second rails app.

Is it possible to get all database data with relations
and write it into `seeds.rb` file ?

It's important to save relations, but do not use primary/foreign keys - to prevent key duplication errors.

Comment: Look into this gem https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db

Comment: Or, this other one: https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump

Comment: what about relations? does this gems write hardcoded IDs into yml/seed.rb files?